# How can I know which page is the "Duplicate page without canonical tag" GSC is reporting

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

The new GSC (Google search console) is showing me a report of "Duplicate page without canonical tag" and sharing a list of URLs.

1. Is there any way to see what's the other url he believes is duplicate with the one in the list?
2. As a rule of thumb, is this a a high priority item in terms of SEO?

Comment: As far as duplication and priority, look at [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think Google tells you which url is the canonical, and which is the duplicate. It's just showing me the duplicates. I also don't think that this is a major concern worth worrying about. Google chose which page to index and so you shouldn't get any major penalties for duplicate URLs. But it's better if you can figure out how to fix them.

Comment: For #1, you'll have to do some legwork yourself. Try using ScreamingFrog SEO Spider to crawl your site and list out all your URL's (if you have a large site, you may need to go premium), download the spreadsheet, and search for a portion of the URL flagged by GSC. You'll probably get a few results for each that you can examine.

Answer (score 2):

Google now tells you which URL it selected as part of the URL Inspection tool in Google Search Console:

[image]

Edit:  **Google retired the `info:` search in March 2019**.   My original answer said to use the "View as search result" option in Google Search Console or search for the URL on Google with an `info:` prefix.  Neither of those options are available anymore.